# "~good gummy candies flavored after them"

Tags: prepositions

This is from [the transcript of a podcast](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/1089175288).

> KIM: Maesil cheong is green plum syrup. My mom actually calls it
> maesil (speaking Korean), and I have no idea how to Romanize that.
> It's a syrup made out of these Korean green plums, which is a very
> particular taste that I remember from my childhood. I'm sure you do,
> too. But it's like these - they taste like a mix between plums and
> green apples, and - but they're so aromatic, and there's, like, really
> good gummy candies flavored **after** them.

I think it is better to change 'after' to 'with' as in [this example in the Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flavour_2?q=flavored).

> *This dish is flavoured with basil and garlic.*

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it would not be correct to use "with" instead of "after."

This is not the most idiomatic phrase (to my American ear), but it is using the word this way:

> [**after**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/after#Preposition), preposition
> 4. In allusion to, in imitation of; following or referencing.
> *We named him **after** his grandfather; a painting **after** Leonardo da Vinci.*

So the speaker is saying that there are gummy candies which are made to tase *as if* they have been flavored with *maesil cheong*, but this does not necessarily mean that they are flavored *with* that substance. The science of [flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor) is quite complex, and it is quite possible that candies can be made to taste like *maesil cheong* despite not containing any of the actual syrup... or it could be that they are, in fact, flavored with *maesil cheong*. But the speaker's use of "after" indicates that they do not contain any real *maesil cheong*.

Comment: Thank you very much.